# Remote desktop on Windows 10 with multiple networks

Tags: windows-10, networking, remote-desktop

I am looking for help on this one, I think I've exhausted all my search options at this point. So here's my issue:

I have several PC's across my organization that I need to remote desktop into. These PC's operate on up to 17 connected network interfaces. When all networks are connected I will only get a black screen via RDP connection. If I disconnect all networks except one and hard reboot the PC, RDP works fine and I can reconnect all the networks to the PC. The conclusion I have come to is the PC is confused on which network interface it's supposed to send RDP through.

Only one of the networks on the PC is for our local intranet the other interfaces are all for testing data traffic.

What I am looking for (and maybe this is wrong) is to bind my RDP connections to one interface or IP.

Comment: As workaround you can try to configure the client (or the server) via Group Policy to use only TCP not UDP for RDP connection. Then only one TCP connection is established and you should not run into problems with multiple networks.

Comment: What operating systems do these PCs have?

Comment: All windows 10 pro (19042)

Answer (score 0):

Associating RDP with one particular network adapter is handled in detail
in the post
[How to set the network interface for RDP in Windows Server 2012?](https://serverfault.com/questions/506081/how-to-set-the-network-interface-for-rdp-in-windows-server-2012)

Below is a summary of one excellent
[answer](https://serverfault.com/a/627967/18736):

- Run PowerShell as Administrator
- Assign network adapter class to a variable:

  ```
    $ts = gwmi Win32_TSNetworkAdapterSetting -filter "TerminalName='RDP-Tcp'" -namespace "root/cimv2/TerminalServices"
  ```
- List the associated adapters:

  ```
    $ts | select -expand DeviceIDList
    $ts | select -expand NetworkAdapterList
  ```

  The first list is a 0-based list of IDs and the second is their
  friendly name, in the same order, where the first is
  `0` which means "All network adapters configured with this protocol".
- Locate the ID of your network adapter in the list by its friendly name
- Enter the following command, for example if this is number `1`:

  ```
    $ts.SetNetworkAdapterLanaID(1)
  ```